# Jquery hover function not working in Opera, Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

This my script. But his working only in firefox. Please help!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".catdiv").hover(function(){
            $(this).animate({"backgroundColor": "#FFD800"}, 300);
          }, function(){
            $(this).animate({"backgroundColor": "#161616"}, 200);
          }); 

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you also post the markup?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a non-jQuery (or non-Javascript for that matter) solution:

```
.catdiv,
.catdiv:hover {
    transition: background-color 500ms;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 500ms;
    -moz-transition: background-color 500ms;
    -ms-transition: background-color 500ms;
    -o-transition: background-color 500ms;
    background-color: #161616
}
.catdiv {
    background-color: #FFD800;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L8r6w/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the jQuery.color plugin to animate background color. It isn't supported in jQuery because most browsers do now natively handle it.

Link: [jQuery Color](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/24/jquery-color-2-1-0/)

Comment: yes, working in Chrome, but still not working in Opera.